# Se cuelga mi aplicación en nodejs con postgresql

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, express

Buenas noches, escribo en esta oportunidad porque estoy trabajando con Postgresql, nodejs y express pero hay un momento que me pasa que como que se cuelga mi aplicación y no me responde la base de datos tampoco :( estuve leyendo la documentación de esta página: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres pero igual me sucede a veces, dicen que debo de usar pg-pool que tengo malo? Este es mi archivo de conexión

```
'use strict' 

const Pool = require('pg-pool') <br/>
var    dbOptions = { <br/>
        "host" : "127.0.0.1", <br/>
        "port" : 5432, <br/>
        "user" : "postgres", <br/>
        "pass" : "secret", <br/>
        "db" : "detalledb", <br/>
        "max" : 20, <br/>
        "idleTimeoutMillis": 1000, <br/>
        "min" : 4, <br/>
        "connectionTimeoutMillis": 1000 <br/>
    }, <br/>
    myConn  = new Pool(dbOptions) <br/>

myConn.connect ((err) => { <br/>
    return (err) ? console.log(`Error al conectarse a PostGres: ${err.stack}`) : console.log(`Conexión establecida con PostGres N°:`) <br/>
}) 
<br/>
myConn.on('error', function (err, client) { <br/>
  console.error('idle client error', err.message, err.stack); <br/>
}) <br/>
module.exports = myConn
```

Si me pudieran ayudar se lo agradecería, soy nueva en nodejs pero he aprendido bastante y me gustaría poder resolver este problema :(

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con "se cuelga"? ¿Qué specs tiene el server/host? ¿Te quedas sin RAM o procesador?

Comment: Necesitas colocar más info. Si tienes algún archivo de log, en qué momentos suele "colgarse", si sospechas que sucede después de una consulta en específico (más si está dentro de un bucle que tenga un bug y lo haga infinito), pueden ser muchas cosas.